# where does the black box in beamer come from?

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer, usetheme Warsaw, whenever I have definition and theorem, there are black boxes. Why is that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}


\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}
  % or ...

  %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
  % or whatever (possibly just delete it)
}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}
      adfa a

    \end{definition}

     adfa a
    \end{frame}



    \end{document}
```

I am using Latex-DVI->PS-PS->PDF
[image]

Comment: I can't see black boxes. Is you system up to date? Please remove the line `\usepackage{default}` or explain, what that is. Please also post a screenshot which shows your result of the above code.

Comment: I cannot see any black box! Up-to-date TL2014 and `pdflatex`

Comment: Please explain in your post, why you don't use `pdflatex` directly. Have a look, if your packages are up to date. If possible: open your file in some other pdf-reader just in order to proove it is not Okulars fault.

Comment: If I use pdflatex, problem solved.

Comment: Could anybody tell the OP that he/she should accept the bunch of answers of his/her questions too!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
[ ...]
```

If that doesn't help, update your TeX distribution!